# How to save the whole class in file named after hashed input?

Tags: python, dictionary

The initialization of my class takes some time (for about an hour). But the result is four arrays of small length. Is there a way to save the result on hard drive and load it if class is fed by same input? I thought it might be like this:

```
    class class_1(a,b):

       def __init__(self):
           self.a = a
           self.b = b

       def load_class(self):
           hashed_input = ...
           if os.path.isdir('data/'+hashed_input):
               ...load out....
           else: self.calc_out()

       def calc_out(self):

       ...takes an hour...


       def save_class(self):
           hashed_input = ...
           dir = '/data/'+hashed_input
           import pathlib
           pathlib.Path(dir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
           np.savez('dir/File.npz', out=self.out)


    args = {a:1, b:2}
    foo = class_1(**args)
    foo.save_class()
```

but I need to use args dict inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe pass `foo.save` as a callback into `calc_out`?

```
def calc_out(self, cb):
    ...
    ...
    cb()

foo.call_out(foo.save)
```